# Make method calls chainable

Tags: ruby, arrays, chaining

I have a Ruby class, and each method on it keeps indices of an array of hashes based on certain conditions.

For example (**code has been edited since original posting**)

```
module Dronestream
  class Strike

    class << self

    ...
    def strike
      @strike ||= all
    end

    def all
      response['strike'] # returns an array of hashes, each individual strike
    end

    def in_country(country)
      strike.keep_if { |strike| strike['country'] == country }
      self
    end

    def in_town(town)
      strike.keep_if { |strike| strike['town'] == town }
      self
    end
    ...
  end
end
```

This way, you can do `Dronestream::Strike.in_country('Yemen')`, or `Dronestream::Strike.in_town('Taizz')`, and each returns an array. But I'd like to be able to do `Dronestream::Strike.in_country('Yemen').in_town('Taizz')`, and have it return only the strikes in that town in Yemen.

But as of now, each separate method returns an array. I know that if I have them return `self`, they'll have the method I need. But then they won't return an array, and I can't call, for example, `first` or `each` on them, like I could an array, which I need to do. I tried to make `Strike < Array`, but then, `first` is an instance method on `Array`, not a class method.

What should I do?

### EDIT

Here is a part of my test suite. Following the answer below, the tests pass individually, but then fail.

```
describe Dronestream::Strike do

  let(:strike) { Dronestream::Strike }

  before :each do
    VCR.insert_cassette 'strike', :record => :new_episodes
    @strike = nil
  end

  after do
    VCR.eject_cassette
  end
  ...
  # passes when run by itself and when the whole file runs together
  describe '#country' do
    let(:country_name) { 'Yemen' }
    it 'takes a country and returns strikes from that country' do
      expect(strike.in_country(country_name).first['country']).to eq(country_name)
    end
  end

  # passes when run by itself, but fails when the whole file runs together
  describe '#in_town' do
    let(:town_name) { 'Wadi Abida' }
    it 'returns an array of strikes for a given town' do
      expect(strike.in_town(town_name).first['town'].include?(town_name)).to be_true 
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite the `method_missing` to handle this.
Return `self` in your `in_country` or `in_town` method. Then when called `first` to it, delivery it to the `all` array to handle.
the code may be like this:

```
module Dronestream
  class Strike

  class << self

  ...
  def all
    ...
  end

  def in_country(country)
    all.keep_if { |strike| strike['country'] == country }
    self
  end

  def in_town(town)
    all.keep_if { |strike| strike['town'] == town }
    self
  end
  ...

  def method_missing(name,*args,&block)
    return all.send(name.to_sym, *args, &block) if all.respond_to? name.to_sym
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: This gave me the methods I needed, but `all` is actually an array of all the strikes. So if I pass `method_missing` to it, it will not narrow the scope. So I had `def strike; @strike || all; end`, and called `keep_if` on strike, thinking it would narrow it with each method chain, but it didn't. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: OK I understand what happened. since your @strike is nil, the strike always return all and @strike never get a value.  you should def it like: `def strike; @strike ||= all; end`

Comment: That seems to work with each method individually. But when I run the test suite, they start to fail because @strike continues to get smaller until it is nil, and doesn't have a `[]` method. Should I reset it in a `before` block? I tried that, and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: How did you reset it? I think set `@strike = nil` should work.

Comment: Maybe you should define a `strike=` or `def clear; @strike = nil; end` method in Dronestrea::Strike. and call `strike.strike = nil` (or `strike.clear`)in the `before :each` method. I'm not very familiar with rspec so not quite sure.

Comment: You're exactly right. That's what I ended up doing. Thanks for hanging in there!